How to get back to math and study abstract algebra?
I graduated (undergrad) with a math degree in 2023 and have been working in finance industry for a year (NOT quant trading, so not much math in my day to day). When I was in college, I tried to take the most challenging math courses offered at the undergraduate level (never took any grad courses as I deemed myself as not smart enough) but I lost motivation after COVID and did the bare minimum to pass the class in some of the classes I took, including but not limited to:

Abstract algebra: I think I got a B (opted for pass/fail so it wouldn't show my grade because at the time I was aiming for law school), but since it was an honors class, B would be as low as it could get. I'm sure I got the lowest grade in the class.
Complex Analysis: I took it during my freshman spring when I wasn't intellectually ready for the class and it was also a universal pass/fail term due to COVID.

Thus I think my foundation in math is not as strong as it should be if I were to make a transition to math. On the other hand, I enjoyed real analysis (also took honors) and set theory (as a reading course) a lot, and did a senior thesis on combinatorics.
I met some enthusiastic people at college and realized they do math in their free time because they simply love math so much, and as much as I loved math too, I couldn't say I could give up on everything else in life just to do math, which is why I made the choice to work in finance.
However, after a year, I miss math very much and am afraid I won't be able to get back to it because I'm getting rusty. I started reading Dummit and Foote again to study algebra but I'm realizing it's a hard book to read.
So my questions are

How do people get back to studying math after a year of not doing any math? Can people get into good graduate programs?
What are some complementary materials I can use to self-study algebra (I remember very little about group theory and close to zero about ring theory) other than my Dummit and Foote textbook?

Thank you.

I think that Dummit and Foote is a nice book to read. It is the most complete math book I know. They rarely skip on details. If you want something more gentle, then maybe try "Notes from the Underground" from Aluffi. It is fairly recent and has a nice conversational style. It takes a somewhat different approach, as it covers ring theory and modules before talking about groups. Besides that it starts from scratch.

Just an alternative suggestions, this is NOT meant to discourage you from pursuing your dream: It is fine to "just read" math for pleasure in your free time. No need to read the most abstract book possible, no need to tackle all the unsolved problem, no pressure to produce results and take exams. Instead, enjoy the beautiful and polished results that are already there!

I am not very familiar with this, but is this question better suited on AcademiaSE?

A year away from mathematics is nothing.

Here are some options:

Speak to a student advisor.

Speak to an instructor that has or will teach the course(s) you are interested in.  Describe your situation to them and ask for their advice.

Get a tutor.

When you enroll in a course, find out what textbook(s) you will be using and read at least one chapter before your class starts.

Attend every class and ask questions if confused.  One of my professors said, ‘the only stupid question is the question that is not asked.’

And most importantly, have faith in yourself!


